# Javascript median using for

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to learn javascript, and I want to find the median of some numbers that I insert into a prompt when I click on the button "find median".

```
  function Media()
 {
     var n = prompt("number of elements?");
     var i = 1;
     var s = 0;
     
     for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
     {
         var m = prompt("insert # " +i);
         s = s+m;
     }
     var media = s/n;
     document.getElementById("rezultat").innerHTML = "result: " +media
 }
```

I made a test with two numbers, 1 and 2, and the median was 6, and i cant figure what i've done wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should parse the result of `prompt` to an integer;

[How to convert a string to an integer in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-to-convert-a-string-to-an-integer-in-javascript)

```js
 function Media() {
     var n = parseInt(prompt("number of elements?"));
     var i = 1;
     var s = 0;
     
     for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
     {
         var m = prompt("insert # " +i);
         m = parseInt(m);
         s = s+m;
     }
     var media = s/n;
     document.getElementById("rezultat").innerHTML = "result: " +media
 }
 
 Media();
```

```html
<div id='rezultat' />
```

Comment: To expand a little on why this is important, your code was doing `"1" + "2" = "12"` then `"12" / 2 = 6` due to JS's use of `+` for string concatenation (In the first sum), and automatic type conversion (In the second).

Comment: If you want that your code works also with float numbers, it is better to use "m = parseFloat(m)" in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should also parse the result of `prompt` using `parseInt`

```
var m = parseInt(prompt("insert # " + i));
```

`s/n` gives the mean of the input. If you are looking for the median, you should use an array to store the inputs and get the element(s) in the middle.